# Python: How to get rid off Default Index in a Dataframe using Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to read a csv file and converting it into a dataframe. Here apart from the columns original columns, I am getting an index column which is being generated automatically.

```
                  Col1          Col2           Col3   
    411580        66349            3            0      
    402645        66887            8            1      
    388542        82777            4            1      
    265353       137481            8            1
```

I have huge records in lakhs, and I did a shuffle and thats why the index is of different range. Here I need to get rid off this index. I tried options such as:

```
    df = pd.read_csv("File_name", index=0)
```

so that column one can be set as index. But I have some other issue in my data manipulating, when I set any of my existing column in csv file as index.

I also tried reindex option. But that also doesn't work. When I try to display Col3, it is coming as below:

```
    df.col3:

                Col3   
    411580        0      
    402645        1      
    388542        1      
    265353        1
```

But I want it as below, without the default index:

```
     Col3   
      0      
      1      
      1      
      1
```

I have tried most of the options mentioned in various other posts, but nothing is working out. It would be great if someone helps me.

Comment: You need `index_col=None` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv, in fact if you didn't pass `index_col` it should have auto generated one also you don't need the `index` param. Also are you trying to skip the index col in your csv or just get rid of it after shuffling? You can do `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Are you trying to reset it with smaller numbers or get rid of it altogether?  I don't think you can get rid of having an index.  You can not print it when printing out, but that's it.

Comment: I am fine with any of the one (After shuffling or even before). I can get rid off it even after reshuffling. Also I tried both index_col=None and df.reset_index(drop=True). Even after that there is an index. I also tried to create a new dataframe by taking the specific column like Col1, Col2, Col3. Even after that, those index like numbers are getting generated.

Comment: "I have huge records in lakhs" is probably meaningful only in India. I know it's 100k but still don't understand what that is trying to say. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A Series or DataFrame will both have an index.  If you just want the values, simply use `.values` to get the numpy array or `df.Col3.tolist()` to get back the array.

```
>>> df.Col3.values
array([0, 1, 1, 1])

>>> df.Col3.tolist()
[0, 1, 1, 1]

>>> df.Col3.values.reshape((len(df.Col3), 1))
array([[0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

Or it you really want a completely useless dataframe but one that displays what you want...

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(['']*len(df), index=df.Col3, columns=[''])
Col3  
0     
1     
1     
1
```

Why would you want a dataframe or series without the index?  The answer to that question may result in the actual solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification